# Error adding module to project: Module already exists: debug

Tags: flutter, android-studio-bumblebee

This flutter project file that I want to import, it's probably an old project, when I try importing it I get this error message of an existing file but, there is none.

I also deleted .idea folder but still showing the same error message "**Error adding module to project: Module already exists: debug**".

Approch already done : - Delete .idea folder from project

Click here to see ScreenShot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBdzo.png

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is related to the flutter SDK dependencies issues. Did you try to upgrade the whole project?

`$ flutter clean` to clean all the related staff

`$ flutter pub get` to get all the corresponding dependencies

Comment: I am unable to open project in android studio then how can i run this command

Comment: you should go to the flutter project directory

Answer (score 0):

Step 1

Delete Two files -
Project > android > .idea
Project > .idea
Delete both .idea file and run

Step 2

Import Project > Import Project from external model

next >next > next

Step 3

Assign flutter file path File > Setting
flutter clean
flutter pub get